# Wrong $area from field calculator (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, polygon, area

The area of the polygons in a layer, calculated by the field calculator with "$area" is wrong (much too big) for some polygons. If I draw the concerned polygon again, the area is calculated correctly. It looks like the polygons really have a wrong size, but the centroids are calculated correctly.

edit: Thanks for your replies so far. [Here](http://johannes-simons.de/Auszug.zip) is an example with some polygons. For some, the area is calculated right, for some not (as I said much too big). For example the polygon with the ID 669. If I redraw it, the area is calculated right. The problem is, I have >1400 polygons, and I don't have the time to check and redraw every single one.

Maybe someone got an explanation/solution?

Comment: Can you provide data which exhibits the problem? If so, this would be worth a bug report. Also, I fail to see the question in your post.

Comment: Is it possible you have multipolygons, and the $area is returning the total area of all constituent pieces?

Comment: Hi @DarrenCope, your solution was correct. Please post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

@DarrenCope made a very good point, your layer contained inconsistencies.

**Please note:** I only posted this as an answer as to include a screenshot of the results, please accept Darren's answer when he posts one as he came up with the correct solution.

I used the **Multiparts to singleparts** function (via *Vector* > *Geometry Tools* > *Multiparts to singleparts*) and then re-calculated the area in a new column with Real numbers and precision of 2:

[image: Area results]

Ironically, enabling the **"on-the-fly"** option for CRS gave the correct results as it often provides wrong values. The CRS I used was: `EPSG:4326 - WGS 84`.

Answer (score 3):

You may have multi-part polygons in your file, and the area column would thus be reflecting the total area of all 'parts' of a polygon. You can use the Vector > Geometry Tools > Multiparts to singleparts tool to create single-part polygons, and calculate the $area on those to get the answer you are expecting.