# How exact is $area?

Tags: field-calculator, area, qgis-2.18

Background: I am doing some area statistics (how much of different properties is used for a specific type of use) based on ACAD-constructions. Both the from dxf converted shapes and the baselayer with all the properties weren't changed, but when I redid the calculations today in order to check for the source of some discrepancies, I stumbled upon several different numbers in my old and new statistics.

Therefore the question: How exact is the $area-function in QGis? Are errormargins by 10 to 100 square metres to be expected? (We're talking usual european field sizes, 50 hectars max)

Comment: Have you checked or changed the projection your data is in? that can affect area calculations: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147147/area-is-calculating-wrong-using-area-in-field-calculator-qgis-2-8-1-wien

Comment: Always the same, always EPSG 25833

Comment: The error does seem to not to exceed 0.3 per cent.

Comment: EPSG:25833 is UTM and applies scale factor 0.9996. It may have an effect but it depends how your data are converted from ACAD into GIS format.

Comment: I believe that a function is a tool that can be configured to receive calculations with a certain error, and the accuracy of your calculations is likely to depend on your source geodata ...

Comment: Yeah, but if the geodata does not change, how can there be differences?